# Filter Data using EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I use EF 4, C# and MS Membership Provider.

I have a GridView with DataSource an EntityDataSource web control.

I would like filter Data using EntityDataSource, filter show apply for the Current Logged-In User, this value should be taken using MS Memebership Provider ( Membership.GetUser(); ).

Now I cannot inf any Parameter in EntityDataSource that would allow me to dot that (in Where/Automatically generate a Where expression using provided parameter ).

Do you have any ideas?

Please provide me a sample of code. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot bind the user's identity declaratively in markup directly to the EntityDataSource. But there are basically two workarounds:

The first is the easier one but requires code-behind. You can use a generic `asp:Parameter` and set its value in code-behind to the user's identity:

Markup:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="MyEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyContext" 
    DefaultContainerName="MyContext" 
    EntitySetName="MyObjectSet" 
    AutoGenerateWhereClause="False"
    Where="it.Username = @Username" 
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyEntityDataSource.WhereParameters["Username"].DefaultValue =
        User.Identity.Name;
}
```

The second way is to create a **custom parameter**. An example how to do that is shown [here](http://blog.einbu.no/2010/02/custom-asp-net-datasource-parameters/). Note: The example is based on a `asp:SqlDataSource` but it should work as well for an EntityDataSource if you make sure that you use `WhereParameters` in the EntityDataSource instead of `SelectParameters` in the SqlDataSource.

Comment: Thanks Slauma, I followed your advice and I implemented the "custom parameter". Thanks for your time