# Store GridView to session C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have page for searching with `GridView` I want to save the whole `GridView` such filter, sort and page after searching to session is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is somewhat related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214670/saving-webcontrols-in-the-session-object) and the answer I would go with is the first one, which is to not save the entire grid and all the controls but just the parameters you need to rebuild the page (like search textbox values, etc.).

Comment: @ourmandave my purpose is when user left page to go next page then he return to previous page which is gridview I want to be same result of search in gridview so I'm thinking to save all values from TextBox to session in method Search_Click then in page_load I do this if(Session["name"] != null) {txtName.Text = Session["name"].ToString(); gridview.dataBind();} but it will not work, so I want something to pass these values to EntityDataSourceName.Where="values from session" How I can pass values to EntityDataSourceName.Where? do you have any idea?

Comment: Would [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5463934/3585500) work? The example is using the user login name but you could say, `MyEntityDataSource.WhereParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = txtName.Text;`. Also see the last answer on [this page](http://forums.asp.net/t/1835939.aspx?Passing+input+parameters+to+the+EntityDataSource) to use a session parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much it help me, I don't know before we have something asp:sessionParameter let me try tomorrow and I will give you my result

Comment: @ourmandave thank you it's work now